# TweetInvi Video Upload Failing With "The tweet cannot be published as some of the medias could not be published!"

Tags: c#, .net, twitter, tweetinvi

I'm having an issue with TweetInvi 0.9.9.7 failing to upload a video. The video is a 9MB MP4 video and I am able to upload it to twitter just fine by using the web interface.
The error message I get is:

> The tweet cannot be published as some of the medias could not be
>   published!

I used fiddler an can see this error message is coming back from the API:

> error=segment size must be <= 1.

According to one of the developers, that error occurs when a video over 5MB is trying to be uploaded to Twitter and is not being sent up in chunks.
https://twittercommunity.com/t/append-call-in-video-upload-api-giving-error/49067

Here is my code, am I doing something wrong? Uploading a file under 5MB works fine but the [official API spec supports video up to 15MB](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/uploading-media)

```
Auth.ApplicationCredentials = new TwitterCredentials("blahblahblah", "censoring private key", "***private, keep out***", "***beware of dog***");
var binary = File.ReadAllBytes(VideoPath);
Tweet.PublishTweetWithVideo("Here is some tweet text", binary);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, I found this undocumented beauty:
`Upload.CreateChunkedUploader();`

Which exposes exactly the functionality I needed to upload this larger file. Here is my new working code for anyone else who may encounter this problem.

```
        var chunk = Upload.CreateChunkedUploader(); //Create an instance of the ChunkedUploader class (I believe this is the only way to get this object)

        using(FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(VideoPath))
        {
            chunk.Init("video/mp4", (int)fs.Length); //Important! When initialized correctly, your "chunk" object will now have a type long "MediaId"
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4900000]; //Your chunk MUST be 5MB or less or else the Append function will fail silently.
            int bytesRead = 0;

            while((bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                byte[] copy = new byte[bytesRead];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, copy, 0, bytesRead);
                chunk.Append(copy, chunk.NextSegmentIndex); //The library says the NextSegment Parameter is optional, however I wasn't able to get it to work if I left it out. 
            }
        }

        var video = chunk.Complete(); //This tells the API that we are done uploading.
        Tweet.PublishTweet("Tweet text:", new PublishTweetOptionalParameters()
        {
            Medias = new List<IMedia>() { video }
        });
```

Important take-aways from this:

- You can't upload files larger than 5MBs without splitting them apart first.
- TweetInvi already has a mechanism to handle this limitation, I just couldn't find any documentation for it.
- The API has a hard limit of 15MBs per video file. [Despite twitter's support site which claims it can handle up to 512MB](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20172128)

> Note: You’ll be prompted if the selected video is not in a supported
>   format. Maximum file size is 512MB. See here for more details about
>   formats.

Comment: I am glad you found this. If you have any suggestion please feel free to post them on github, I will always do my best to improve the library.

Comment: Hey, thanks! Will do! Your library is amazing. I rely on it heavily, yet this was the first and only thing I hit a road block with and ultimately, your library already handled it. I just needed to look harder to find it.